# PyTorch & Google Colab: ImageFolder doesn't load all images

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm using PyTorch for a 'Cats vs Dogs' image classification task (9999 images of Cats and 9999 images of Dogs) on Google colab with the following piece of code to create a data loader:

```
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(r'/content/drive/My Drive/kaggle/trainset/trainset',transform = transforms.ToTensor())
```

and 'data' has a length of 6594 (vs 19998 expected). I try restarting the runtime and I get a different number of images every time. Then I tried running the same piece of code in a jupyter notebook and it worked as expected, loading all 19998 images. What am I doing wrong in colab?

Comment: I'd try copying the data out of `/content/drive/` first. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the problem and the path was /content/usage then I moved my datafolder to another folder called dataset it works!

[image: how i moved in colab]

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and just solved, let's say you want to classify cat and fish [simple_example_link](https://github.com/rebeen/beginners-pytorch-deep-learning/tree/master/chapter2) using Google Colab, you should first download the images by the `download.py` in the given link (run this download.py in a cell of the colab) and then you will see the train, val and test folders will be created in the left-hand side of the Colab (see in the attached image) and then normally you just add the path of the folders to the `ImageFolder` as I have done.
if you want to mount your drive, simply click on the MOUNT DRIVE as it can be seen in the image below the left-hand side [image]